# How can restrict a user from accessing the admin panel in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I have created a web app but I want to prevent a user from accessing the admin panel in Django web app.The user will only be allow to access the custom created site but not Django's default admin site.

Comment: By default, only users with staff/superusers attribute can access the admin site. So long as you are not creating your users with these attributes, shouldn't it be OK?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understood what is your issue really well, but I'm going to list some things related to what you asked.

1 - If you want to log in as the admin user, and as another user in the site, that is not possible, if you are logged in as the admin in the admin panel you are going to be logged in as the admin in the site. So if you want to log in as a different user in the site, just logout of the admin panel, and login as the user that you want to use.

2 - If you want to separate the project in two different folders, one for the admin part, and one for the rest of the application, you can create an app using the command: `django-admin startapp name_of_the_app`. This will create a folder with some default python files that you can use to separate the project.

Hope I've helped, if I wasn't able to solve your issue, feel free to contact me.

Comment: Close enough,thanks.The issue is I want to user X to login to the site (front-end), but the same user X should not be automatically be logged in to /admin app (back-end) and Vice versa.Technically speaking the login session in /admin app(back-end)  to be totally  different from the general user site (front-end).

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's possible, as I said, but why is that a problem tho? And back/front-end is not really well put in that sentence, since the admin panel is going to be accessed by the admin user, it can be called front-end.

Comment: Only users with is_staff (and is_superuser) can log in to the admin.